# Adding Graceful shutdown in Java application

Tags: java, spring, docker, kubernetes, graceful-shutdown

I need to add graceful shutdown for application that will be deployed using ***kubernetes***.

I was able to find the documentation for graceful shutdown from spring boot version 2.3.0

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.graceful-shutdown.

There are two types of applications in which I need to add graceful shutdown

***1. Spring boot application version less than 2***

***2. Normal Spring applications without spring boot.***

kindly suggest me the best practices and approaches . Thanks in advance

Thanks,
Manzoor

Answer (score 0):

For a spring based application you already found the documentation.

If a webapp (without spring) wants to react before Tomcat is going down, it can implement a [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

If you have a generic java application, you may want to install a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).